# Is the crossed product $\mathcal{K} \rtimes G$ a groupoid algebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, groupoids

Suppose G, a discrete group acting on the compact operators $\mathcal{K}$ by automorphism of C*-algebra $\mathcal{K}$. Can we view the crossed product as a groupoid C*-algebra of some groupoid?

This question occurred to me when I was thinking of possible formulation of Baum-Connes conjecture for projective representation of the group.

Comment: Since all automorphisms of $\mathcal K$ are inner, the crossed product ${\mathcal K} \rtimes G$ is $*$-isomorphic to ${\mathcal K} \otimes \mathrm{C}^*_\lambda(G)$. The latter is a groupid $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA if you look at this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609784v2.pdf (page 5, second paragraph from top), this action by $G$ comes from a 2-cocycle from 2nd cohomology group of $G$, and the crossed product $\mathcal{K} \rtimes G$ highly depends on that cocycle. So can you please clarify the 1st statement?

Comment: You are right. It was isomorphic to ${\mathcal K}\otimes\mathrm{C}^*_\lambda(G,\bar{\omega})$. It isn't clear if it's a groupoid $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra.

Comment: yes, even not clear for finite groups(for trivial group its obvious only)!

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, describing a C*-algebra as a twisted groupoid C"-algebra is often good enough.  So @Ozawa's last comment could be what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen Packer-Raeburn Stabilization trick?

> Judith A. Packer and Iain Raeburn, *On the structure of twisted group $C^*$-algebras*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **334** no 2 (1992), 685-718, doi:[10.1090/S0002-9947-1992-1078249-7](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1992-1078249-7)

Specially Theorem 3.4 therein establishes that the algebra is Morita equivalent to a Twisted Group $C^*$-algebra, summarizing the answer by N. Ozawa and the correction above.

By considering the trick of viewing the algebra $K\rtimes G$ as a locally trivial bundle with a $G$-action over a contractible $G$-space $X$ (for instance, the total space of the universal $G$-Bundle $EG$, but also the space $\underline{E}G$ works), you can see the $C^*$-algebra in question is Morita equivalent to the algebra of sections of the Fell bundle over the transformation groupoid $X\rtimes G$. This has been documented in Kumjian's monograph

> Alex Kumjian, *On equivariant sheaf cohomology and elementary $C^*$-bundles*, J. Operator Theory **20** (1988), no. 2, 207–240 ([journal pdf](http://www.theta.ro/jot/archive/1988-020-002/1988-020-002-002.pdf))

Other references on this kind of tricks include

> Siegfried Echterhoff, *Morita Equivalent Twisted Actions and a New Version of the Packer-Raeburn Stabilization Trick*, Journal of the London Mathematical Society **50** Issue 1 (1994) 170–186, doi:[10.1112/jlms/50.1.170](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/50.1.170)

and part 5 here:

> Noé Bárcenas, *Twisted geometric K-homology for proper actions of discrete groups*, Journal of Topology and Analysis (2018) doi:[10.1142/S1793525319500729](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793525319500729), arXiv:[1501.06050](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06050).

Comment: The first link above doesn't have a Theorem 3.4 (Thanks to Michael Murray for pointing this out_! It's possible the paper Nicolas meant was: Judith A. Packer and Iain Raeburn, _Twisted crossed products of C∗-algebras_, Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. **106** (1989), no. 2, 293–311, [MR1002543](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1002543), doi:[10.1017/S0305004100078129](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100078129), which _does_ have what looks to be a relevant Theorem 3.4